# Relay resets microcontroller - Is my flyback diode wired correctly for this relay circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, relay

I built a relay circuit with an ESP32 as the microcontroller and got it made by JLPCB.

When I switch on/off a 110V contactor using my relay (100W start up current,) my ESP32 resets intermittently.

I have an optocoupler but using same shared same supply with the ESP32.

I tried a Sansmart 5V 8 channel relay using shared VCC with relay and ESP32 and experienced no reset.

This makes me think there is something wrong with my relay circuit design.

Everything looks the same except maybe the flyback diode. Did I connect it properly or choose the correct diode?

My custom relay:

[image: My custom relay]

Sansmart relay:

[image: Sansmart Relay]

Comment: what is the purpose of the optoisolator in your circuit?

Comment: [Cargo cult design.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_science)  Opto isolators are intended to transfer signals between circuits that have no common ground.  The separate grounds are intended to provide safety isolation between high and low voltage circuits and noise isolation to prevent voltage glitches on the power supply of on circuit from affecting the operation of another circuit.  The common relay modules use opto isolators but then tie the grounds of both sides together.  This circumvents the isolation properties, making the opto isolators into expensive transistors.

Comment: The relay module manufacturers put opto isolators in because they think they need them, but they do it incorrectly because their "engineers" don't understand things very well.  Then along come hobbyists who copy the relay module circuit and understand it even less.  Cargo cult copy of a cargo cult design.

Comment: Why is the LED placed in series with the optocoupler?

Comment: as others have pointed out, the optos are redundant in this circuit. Your diode is correctly placed, but you can still get spikes on Vcc of 0.7V with it, which might be enough to upset your microcontroller. Better practice is to directly drive the transistor from the uC pin, but drive the relay from some other DC source if one is available. Relays and uC circuits don't play that well together in general.

Comment: in this design I'd also be concerned about the transistor turning off properly because there is nothing holding it's base at 0V when the opto is off. A 1k resistor from base to ground would be a good idea.

Comment: @lundin because the OP copied the design from the pictured PCB :-)

Comment: Anyway, what's wrong with ULN2803 and 12V/24V coil relays? Approximately hundred times cheaper than this optocoupler design... you get the flybacks for free.

Comment: So just to be sure, does the ESP32 reset also by toggling the relay without the load, or only when the relay toggles with the 100W load? (Hint: huge difference what and where the issue might be.)

Comment: @Justme relay works fine without 100w load

Comment: @Lundin so with ULN2803 transistor, I can omit the extra optocoupler and fly back diode? I used 5v since it is the same voltage as Esp32 so I figured to avoid another voltage. Is 12v/24v better idea for relay? Lower amp? draw?

Comment: @user2727691 Mainly 12V and 24V are industry standards and if you happen to have those available, you can separate the coil supply from your 5V net. Relay coils don't need an exact, regulated voltage either. ULN2803 has flyback built-in, it's basically working like a NPN BJT array of sorts. If you wish even more rugged parts than that, you can go with a "smart" high side driver which are based on N-channel MOSFET and suitable for industrial/automotive.

Comment: Anyway for the current design, you need to narrow down the problem. Hook up the load, measure the voltage input before the regulator with a scope when you toggle the relay. Then measure the voltage output. Then measure the CPU reset. This should narrow it down to one of the likely suspects: bad input filtering, or the regulator getting hiccups backwards from EMF, or the MCU going nuts for some other reason. Also, can this MCU tell you the reset reason? Was it brown-out detect, was it hardware reset, was it watchdog etc.

Comment: @jre without making any other changes(capacitor etc) , if I separate the ground and vcc of relay coil and the control IC using optocoupler, will this problem be fixed? Is this type of isolation enough to address coil noise ?

Comment: @Lundin thanks. With ULN2803, I still need optocoupler, correct? I can just omit the fly back diode with this part. Can you give me an example part # of the smart high side driver? Anything with built in transistor with optocoupler so i can simplified this circuit?

Comment: @user2727691 No you don't need an optocoupler anywhere. (They should literally not be used anywhere, they are unreliable and expensive and digital isolators replaced them some 10 years back.) Especially if you don't drive the coil from the 5V net but a separate source.

Comment: As for high side drivers, you unfortunately have to marry Infineon. They have pretty much monopoly on these parts after the merger with IR and what little competition they have left is way behind quality-wise. Example: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/smart-low-side-high-side-switches/high-side-switches/profet-plus-24v-automotive-smart-high-side-switch/ These are great parts but if you want to buy them, Infineon will unfortunately tell you to get lost, though more politely phrased as "led time 52 weeks". They have a very long tradition of horrible logistics.

Comment: Thanks @lundin. Will adopt ULN2803 by your suggestion. Didn’t optocoupler was obsolete. Good to know!

Comment: @user2727691 Not obsolete as such, but an old-fashioned design. Check out for example https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/standard-digital-isolators.html.

Comment: @lundin. thanks. I see this 16ch sansmart relay uses two ULN2803 but also uses 16 817c optocoupler. Is this redundant design? https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71iAO6BUk9L._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Comment: @LUNDIN, do I need to replace the optocoupler with a digital isolator then? Does ULN2803 contain digital isolator or I need a separate one? I searched ULN2803 example and ppl still uses optocoupler with this chip?

Comment: @user2727691 No! You shouldn't need any galvanic isolation at all other than what the relay itself already provides. As pointed out in an answer, your problems here are likely related to badly designed grounding for this ESP32 and ground currents. That's what you get for using hobbyist MCUs I guess... too late to switch to something more suitable for industrial applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

When the relay sparks, it will throw noise in both coil pins.

First make sure you have a decoupling cap C1 between VCC and GND close to the relay. 100nF ceramic is fine. If you already have a decoupling cap there, no need to add more.

Then you can:

Add C3, it should be low value because Q3 will short it when it turns on: 10nF ceramic. That saved my TPIC6C596 from rebooting each time it switched a relay.

And/or swap the resistor and the LED, so the resistor is in series with the GPIO pin and somewhat protects it from EMI, but especially from C2, which should be 10nF ceramic to short noise to ground before it gets to the micro.

If it still crashes, this could means your load really makes a lot of noise at turn off. That happened here with some motorized valves. I put snubbers across them, and no more problems. To drive contactors, I didn't need snubbers.

Note the optocoupler is mostly useless here.

Your board also matters. If you don't have good grounding, then it's much easier to get this sort of problems.

If "VCC" is 3V3, and you're really using the output of that AMS1117 to drive a relay, then... that's a bad idea. If your VCC is 5V from a USB port, then you should consider adding a large enough electrolytic cap there so it doesn't drop down too much and reboot your micro when the relay turns on.

Comment: If you need to sprinkle decoupling caps around the coil, I'd say that the root cause is elsewhere. Driving the relay from the TTL level net used by everything else is probably not a good idea, simple as that. Though in worst case the MCU itself is bad at dealing with conducted EMI.

Comment: Yeah I was surprised when TPIC6C596, which is specified as solenoid driver, reset itself when driving relays. But well, the board was made, and the capacitors fixed it. ESP32 modules also have no good ground plane, it's a 2 layer PCB with just traces on both sides.

Comment: Ouch really? I think you might be onto something then. Could as well be something like ground currents messing things up then, I didn't even consider that. Always a nasty problem to trouble-shoot...

Comment: Thanks bobflux. Will add your suggestions to my design

Comment: If you still have trouble, put a picture of the board/layout. I think the reason it works with the board with the "cargo cult" optocouplers is that this board has separate ground and VCC pins for the relays, which kinda entices you to wire them separately back to the power supply instead of connecting to your board, which would somewhat protect your board against EMI from the inductive load... only "somewhat" of course.

Comment: But hey, since you have an opto you're not using, you could even cut the ground/VCC traces so you have two separated grounds/VCCs on your board, and wire the "relay side" of that VCC/ground to the power supply just like with the Chinese relay board... that will not apply if you're using 5V from USB on the ESP32 of course, cause then you wouldn't wire it to the power supply, but to your board, so back to square one.

Comment: @Lundin I think it's because this accursed chip has only one ground pin, so when the relay EMI kicks it, it gets some ground lift, and the voltage threshold for the reset pin depends on whatever voltage the internal ground is at...

Comment: @bobflux thanks. I just tested my board with a bench PSU. It seems like reset is caused by voltage drop on the ESP32 caused by switching the 100W load. When I crank the voltage down to 4.5 when ESP32 is barely on, one relay switch causes it to reset. When I crank the voltage up to 5.3, ESP32 works without reset. Based on this, should I add more capacitor to the VCC side of ESP32 to keep it going when there is a voltage drop?

Comment: If it is due to +5V dropping under load due to relay current, then it should also happen without the load. You can add an electrolytic capacitor like 100-470µF on +5V (not on 3V3) to prevent +5V dropping when the 5V relay switches. If it is a power supply issue, be aware that the AMS1117 regulator on these ESP modules is the cheapest they could find and rather poor. I replace them with LDL1117 (or any decent LDO) and that solves some spurious reboots issues...

Comment: @bobflux thanks. If I separate the relay vcc and ground with Esp32 and use independent psu and optocoupler, will these issues be solved?

Comment: I have no idea, if the problem is the +5V supply not being strong enough to drive the relay, as your test seems to show, then a better fix would be a better power supply...

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit most likely looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDBbs3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Most voltage regulators can't absorb voltage spikes on the input side.  They regulate their own output, but the spike caused by switching the relay will cause a spike on the 5V output.

Your diode appears to be a surface mount version of the 1N4007.  The current and voltage ratings of the 4007 are much higher than you need and may lead to a higher voltage spike on the 5V line.

1. Use a "smaller" diode for your flyback.  Try a 1N4148 or a Schottky diode.
2. Install a 100nF capacitor in parallel to relay.  Connect it from 5V to ground, by right at the relay coil.  You can tack on to the back of your PCB.

Comment: Isn't the size of the spike relative to the diode forward voltage? I don't think 1N400x is any worse than 1N4148 in that regard? Should be around 0.7V.

Comment: The 1N4148 is faster than the 1N4007.  The 1N4007 forward voltage is "around" 0.7V, tends to be higher.  The 1N4148 is "around" 0.7V, but tends to be lower.

Comment: These are relatively slow pulses and it would seem that the difference between 1N400x and 1N4148 are otherwise close to negligible. I guess all of this depends on what regulator that's used. If worried, one could place a diode across the regulator or maybe even a TVS on the output pin, but it sounds overkill for most cases.

Comment: I think more than anything it is that the power supply can't "swallow" the spikes.  If it's a wall wart, then no telling what's in it.  The long(ish) wires would also act as an inductor, so the voltage spike would have to be absorbed by something closer to the relay.